# how to align group of images?

Tags: html, image, bootstrap-4, thumbnails

new  web developer and i am stuck with images alignment that i am trying to add to my page.I added the images just fine but i want the images to cover the whole space of the previous div i don't care about the aspect ratio but only alignment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test file</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/23/12/53/clock-1274699_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/11/17/00/cook-366875_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/25/12/48/go-pro-1478810_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="images/" class="img-thumbnail imgL">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want the images to cover whole blue space

[image: 1]

Comment: This is how: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/DpmnK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this solves your problem.
object-fit property is used to specify how an img should be resized to fit its container (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test file</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<style>
.fixHeight{

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/23/12/53/clock-1274699_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail fixHeight">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/11/17/00/cook-366875_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail fixHeight">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/25/12/48/go-pro-1478810_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail fixHeight">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="images/" class="img-thumbnail imgL">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot that  works like charm, exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

Since the images are not of equal aspect ratios, it won't be possible to align them completely without distortion or cropping. With distortion, the following can be done

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>test file</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/23/12/53/clock-1274699_960_720.jpg"class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 180px; width: 100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/11/17/00/cook-366875_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 180px; width: 100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/25/12/48/go-pro-1478810_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" style="height: 180px; width: 100%">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                    <a href="#">
                    <img src="images/" class="img-thumbnail imgL">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Comment: For me, I did. Attaching a screenshot in my answer. The images do get distorted but they are aligned

Comment: that was for previous answer i am sorry, It now surely works can you please explain why the percentage did not work as expected.

Comment: The percent thing was expanding the image to the full pixel value of the original image which is much bigger than what is to be displayed

Answer (score 2):

change your HTML to this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test file</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<style>
.full_height {
    height: 250px;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/23/12/53/clock-1274699_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail full_height">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/06/11/17/00/cook-366875_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail full_height">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/25/12/48/go-pro-1478810_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail full_height">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="#">
                <img src="images/" class="img-thumbnail imgL">
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It aligns the images but it also expands them a lot downwards, it increases the  size of previous div (the blue rectangle i was referring to in my question)

Comment: so, just change `height:100%;` to `height:250px;`. also i updated the code above.

Comment: Thank you that  works perfecly fine but  can you please explain why  that percentage worked as that way?

Comment: cuz it tries to use whole height.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
<style>
    .img-thumbnail {    
        height: 100%;
}
</style
```

Comment: it aligns the image but doesn't work as expected, as it further stretches the size of div(the blue rectangle)

Comment: @Nnnnn: You mean that you just want to resize the first image, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 img-holder">
   <a href="#">
     <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/23/12/53/clock-1274699_960_720.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
   </a>
</div>
```

Based from your initial code. You may just add a class e.g .img-holder with the following values:

```
.img-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    height: 250px;
}
```

To fill up the blue space you are referring to, you may just have the following value for the img tag.

```
.img-thumbnail {
   max-height: 100%;
}
```